# Problem while trying to replace some lines using sed

Tags: wordpress, bash, ubuntu, scripting, ubuntu-server

I was trying to create a script that installs Wordpress automatically in Ubuntu Server, for a college project. The problem comes when I try to insert the authentication keys inside of the wp-config.php file. The keys are obtained through an url that generates them, and can be obtained using curl. The output of the command: `curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/` is something like this:

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         '$+ef);AyI`T!+<2gPHrG%R^&6NX`E~+TumT qdMWY&QP.l) TYz2fENG}[bCc8~:');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'omDNxow|,(WIuk-pS MRG&P&2Shlk8Y=Q<PH|+fA;T`~b:?I- <Q|ng}~TX|@=^s');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '3d[bU]VTc+R84#+~TYAO#?c+FQLWVxDq&1wGUZC;$d@n1)9We VXrGIJN3cX*d%E');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'S(No,u/>6(Q4!2(u6ri-LRAp8uESFY{__ZWbH(nP]YOC3WA@JvWkkwrIY<^Dvm b');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'ph512NCyJ?3]g|a|<5@fH5cCX&Rw{%+}Sm?gmVQ6WRnj-]N2]rg+i{21<-05`H>o');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'hig|pYFPmF6w1Jm&R:U{ZDvxkeOW*#63ys!b7]FT|v*Crm>8kK!;hw=`hovm)Rqp');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'S[40r?y~.*-]Z9]0qLEOTp}}+T|lO|p-Qz|^h}:C{s&_X]kOkPp+uKuOhy3j`sf9');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'Ph|CZMq3C]<p2*G=qV2PSj5o4mYjTg!NX`[G---_W%w2H:`e6Q@1!a:]vYWxQlP#');
```

And the default values look like this: `define( 'AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );`

I want to insert the keys in the same lines where the sample lines are. If I just append the output of curl to the document, it won't work. The problem is that the keys are formed by a lot of conflictive characters, which cause errors when I try to replace the lines using sed.
The bash script I have done to replace the lines doesn't work because of the conflictive characters. This is the script:

```
key_names=("AUTH_KEY SECURE_AUTH_KEY LOGGED_IN_KEY NONCE_KEY AUTH_SALT SECURE_AUTH_SALT LOGGED_IN_SALT NONCE_SALT")
key_values=($(curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ | awk -F"'" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' | awk 'length >30'))

# iterate over each element to insert the keys in wp-config.php proper line
for ((i=0; i<${#key_values[@]}; i++)); do
    sed -i "s/define( '${key_names[i]}', '.*' );/define( '${key_names[i]}', '${key_values[i]}' );/" $WP_CONF_FILE
done
```

I tried by just redirecting the output of the curl command to the file, but it doesn't work, the lines need to be inserted where the example lines are. I also tried to replace the lines with sed (using the script above), but it doesn't work because of the conflictive characters. I also tried asking ChatGPT, but it didn't really come up with any solution.

Any idea of how could I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: White some points are unclear here, consider building a utility that just prints out your required `define('AUTH_KEY', .....)`. You ave everything you need with `define( '${key_names[i]}', '${key_values[i]}'` . I think this would be much easier to manage in an `awk` script. If there is pre-code, or post-code that needs to be added, that could be where sed's `r filename` could help. Sorry don't have time to write it for your today. Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by sed's r filenane? I don't know that functionality

Comment: Asking ChatGPT for software is like if your car breaks down and you ask a plumber how to fix it. Maybe you'll get lucky and they know enough about cars to get you on the road for a while but a mechanic would probably have a more robust solution.

Comment: [sed tutorial, reading in a file  with the r cmd](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` usually isn't the best choice for substitutions using input values since it doesn't understand literal strings, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for details. Also using a shell loop is very slow, as is running `sed` multiple times on your input file, and it introduces rainy day cases where a subsequent substitution might replace a change made by an earlier substitution.

I think this might be what you're trying to do, using any awk and just modifying the input file once for all keys together:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

curl -k -s 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/' |
awk -F"'" '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    NR == FNR {
        map[$2] = $4
        next
    }
    /^define\(/ && ($2 in map) {
        $4 = map[$2]
    }
    { print }
' - "$WP_CONF_FILE" > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" "$WP_CONF_FILE"
```

When I ran your `curl` command from the command-line I got the same kind of output you show but when I ran it from a script I got no output so when I removed the `-s` option to see if it was reporting any failures I get `curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.`. I had to add `-k` to skip certificate validation to get it to work from a script.

Copying an example file google found on github to use as sample input:

```
$ curl -k -s 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-config-sample.php' > wp-config-sample.php
$ cat wp-config-sample.php
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the installation.
 * You don't have to use the web site, you can copy this file to "wp-config.php"
 * and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * Database settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */



/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

I tested my script using:

```
$ cp wp-config-sample.php orig
$ WP_CONF_FILE='wp-config-sample.php' ./tst.sh
$ diff orig wp-config-sample.php
51,58c51,58
< define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
< define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );
---
> define( 'AUTH_KEY',         '6O 0_j!ReXNj`Uf5#Q+}CB@db6HA(I~+u`i,fiyIYSp|Rj{!p>oytFo}8Sx8!Fm^' );
> define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'l)Z3t=c1TXI7N)[zV6?i:l`,MjG?Q]a~Wvp,+P+9|w;hxi1Rkc1)`~/mUA1S>Tb{' );
> define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'hgnD89/M7:GrSd|%0U.}26k)a;S:-xFW_iQA0ppNm-J_8=:hKjoM>Q&XT^&!|lbl' );
> define( 'NONCE_KEY',        ')X, Tk%(uihbq[caL}dvR{Tt55D!:m+ePK`4h(|li~mcE8Mg._gXxgo)++&N6Lb+' );
> define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'lF?JrQUDFfVZo.HHGa^m=-;?Q#c2ViC!sfNvyu[[6+0vl4jo41w-q+%!~hrm`>D~' );
> define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '2cWJ5Z{j[(QZ:h/M_0@&f>;F`q)y1A@z; Y%Ra^Vf;R}Yvtd7.CftK-BzO|+!S ~' );
> define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   ':jt]g7smA2Bw,|Caf|RJ4=Y)g|-c/afF-X W7),.8WRm|<n=rorm):~i!A^]VwJD' );
> define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'SrW-S`ylE0Onco3A*rMp7;JQ}Pap}P_*|E+pDt>3p:Yz-r6*8RktYQYAMLh}nuL*' );
```

By the way, in your original script there was no need to hard-code an array `key_names[]` when you could've just read the names from the `curl` output like you're reading the values, e.g. with 2 indexed arrays as you have:

```
while IFS="'" read -r _ name _ value _; do
    key_names+=( "$name" )
    key_values+=( "$value" )
done < <(curl -k -s 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/')
```

or a single associative array:

```
declare -A key_names2values
while IFS="'" read -r _ name _ value _; do
    key_names2values["$name"]="$value"
done < <(curl -k -s 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/')
```

Also `| awk -F"'" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' | awk 'length >30')` could've just been `| awk -F"'" '{print $4}'` or even `| curl -d"'" -f4`.